# Issue with people picker window. Sharepoint 2016-2019

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, people-picker

We've got a blank people picker window after installation. Has anybody met this?[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, the `PickerHierarchyControl.js` is **missing** in your server.
This file is located at the below path:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS
```

**So as a quick fixe,**

- Make sure that you have cleared the browser cache,
- If the issue still exists, I would suggest copying the same file `PickerHierarchyControl.js` from another working farm/server and paste it into your farm on the same path!

Comment: Hello Mohamed. Thanks for your reply. A strange thing that I have this js file on the server. Even if I overwrite this file from working farm it isn't helpful.

Comment: Hi Andrey, Sad to hear that, please tell me How many servers you have on your farm? have you recently configured AAM?

Comment: We have this issue in the two different farms. 1st farm is single-server sp2016, 2nd is 2-server sp2019 farm. Both farms had been deployed with SpAutoInstaller. AAM is configured by default.

Comment: Looks like there is a specific security policy applied on your side that may block such files!

Comment: Yeah, could be. That is exactly what we are investigating right now.. =)

Comment: Finally we found the root cause. It was 'malicious' 'Query Strings' in the IIS Request Filtering module.